# How to map out data from api

Tags: reactjs

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

function App() {
  const [Users, fetchUsers] = useState([])

  const getData = () => {
    fetch('https://api.hatchways.io/assessment/students')
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res)
        fetchUsers(res)
      })
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getData()
  }, [])

  //
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <ul>
        {Users.map((item, i) => {
          return <li key={i}>{item.city}</li>
        })}
      </ul>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

It seems to console out all the data but it doesn't exactly map them out on the screen like I wanted. The bottom is what it appears to have done.

```
{students: Array(25)}students: Array(25)0: {city: 'Fushë-Muhurr', company: 'Yadel', email: 'iorton0@imdb.com', firstName: 'Ingaberg', grades: Array(8), …}1: {city: 'Sanghan', company: 'Avamm', email: 'cboards1@weibo.com', firstName: 'Clarke', grades: Array(8), …}2: {city: 'Kugesi', company: 'Skalith', email: 'lromanet2@wired.com', firstName: 'Laurens', grades: Array(8), …}3: {city: 'Krajan', company: 'Mybuzz', email: 'bskitt3@aboutads.info', firstName: 'Berti', grades: Array(8), …}4: {city: 'Huiqi', company: 'Avavee', email: 'msummerley4@craigslist.org', firstName: 'Mureil', grades: Array(8), …}5: {city: 'Jianghong', company: 'Twinte', email: 'rcoryndon5@cargocollective.com', firstName: 'Robbyn', grades: Array(8), …}6: {city: 'Sanxi', company: 'Buzzster', email: 'seykel6@examiner.com', firstName: 'Sheena', grades: Array(8), …}7: {city: 'Huancheng', company: 'Edgeblab', email: 'mewen7@ycombinator.com', firstName: 'Minnnie', grades: Array(8), …}8: {city: 'Luoxiong', company: 'Fadeo', email: 'riban8@hubpages.com', firstName: 'Rory', grades: Array(8), …}9: {city: 'Toulon', company: 'Yakidoo', email: 'lroxby9@cam.ac.uk', firstName: 'Lenna', grades: Array(8), …}10: {city: 'Lazo', company: 'Photolist', email: 'rfitzalana@parallels.com', firstName: 'Rosalynd', grades: Array(8), …}11: {city: 'Bichura', company: 'Babblestorm', email: 'srapellib@adobe.com', firstName: 'Stephanie', grades: Array(8), …}12: {city: 'Chvalšiny', company: 'Mynte', email: 'mmacdirmidc@plala.or.jp', firstName: 'Maire', grades: Array(8), …}13: {city: 'Itaparica', company: 'Photospace', email: 'nshepherdd@desdev.cn', firstName: 'Nicoline', grades: Array(8), …}14: {city: 'Praia da Vitória', company: 'Vitz', email: 'ythornse@github.com', firstName: 'Yoshi', grades: Array(8), …}15: {city: 'Sambir', company: 'Twitterwire', email: 'mtothef@shutterfly.com', firstName: 'Marna', grades: Array(8), …}16: {city: 'Sarulla', company: 'Blogpad', email: 'okearyg@g.co', firstName: 'Orelia', grades: Array(8), …}17: {city: 'Ochakovo-Matveyevskoye', company: 'Mydeo', email: 'mswaith@cafepress.com', firstName: 'Moses', grades: Array(8), …}18: {city: 'Youxi Chengguanzhen', company: 'Avaveo', email: 'fnusseyi@skyrock.com', firstName: 'Fonsie', grades: Array(8), …}19: {city: 'Limoges', company: 'Tazzy', email: 'srydingsj@phoca.cz', firstName: 'Skelly', grades: Array(8), …}20: {city: 'Łobżenica', company: 'Quatz', email: 'obrennekek@yellowbook.com', firstName: 'Olly', grades: Array(8), …}21: {city: 'Divo', company: 'Gigazoom', email: 'nbadwickl@nifty.com', firstName: 'Norby', grades: Array(8), …}22: {city: 'Sortavala', company: 'Eamia', email: 'mmichiem@nifty.com', firstName: 'Melody', grades: Array(8), …}23: {city: 'Taupo', company: 'Midel', email: 'jwillougheyn@psu.edu', firstName: 'Janice', grades: Array(8), …}24: {city: 'Krajandadapmulyo', company: 'Wikibox', email: 'ggallymoreo@mashable.com', firstName: 'Geraldine', grades: Array(8), …}length: 25[[Prototype]]:
```

Answer (score 0):

You are storing the entire response into the state variable `Users` and the response is an object. You can not apply `.map()` on the object. Just do something like this.

```
const getData = () => {
  fetch("https://api.hatchways.io/assessment/students")
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
      fetchUsers(res.students);
    });
};
```

or below.

```
<ul>
  Users.students.map((item, i) => {
     return <li key={i}>{item.city}</li>
  })}
</ul>
```